# Python not installing packages in venv, although it is activated

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have my venv activated but still pip installs packages in another folder.
(venv) C:\Users\JB\PycharmProjects\Flask_project>pip install marshmallow
Requirement already satisfied: marshmallow in c:\users\JB\documents\anaconda\lib\site-packages (3.10.0)

Comment: Please, add more information of what you are doing.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) Your best bet here is to do your research, [search](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. If you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help. Good luck!'

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you are using a command that changes the location of your instalation directory. Another thing I can assume from the problem you are having is that the packages are already installed on your venv, can you please test it ?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, the problem was I had some manual packages which were imported, and was causing problem, creating another venv solved the problem.